# Delete consecutive lines that are duplicates, Unix

Tags: unix

I'm struggling to figure this out, if I could just delete duplicates I'd be happy but they need to be consecutive.

Input:

```
This is not consecutive
This is consecutive
This is consecutive
This is consecutive
This is not consecutive
```

Output:

```
This is not consecutive
This is not consecutive
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard `uniq` program, which deletes consecutive matching lines:

```
% uniq foo
This is not consecutive
This is consecutive
This is not consecutive
```

When run without arguments, you'll still have one of the "This is consecutive" lines in each batch of duplicates.  However (and I admit, I didn't know this before today) `uniq` includes the `-u` option to only print lines that are not duplicates!

```
% uniq -u foo                                                                                                                                                                                                              
This is not consecutive
This is not consecutive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either sort your input, and perhaps use `sort`'s `-u` option:

```
$ sort -u inp
This is consecutive
This is not consecutive
```

or if original order is important, you can use this classic awk snippet:

```
$ awk '!a[$0]++' inp
This is not consecutive
This is consecutive
```

Note that the latter solution stores each unique line of input in an array, so for very long input files you may be limited by available memory.